# Cisco routers "loopback"

Tags: firewall, nat, cisco, loopback

I have Cisco RV220W.

I have configured with NAT, and its working good from outside. (From WAN)

But when I is on LAN-side, and visit my ip-address, for instance http://83.213.21.32:80
I am beeing sent to the router login-page.

How can I fix this? What configuration should I look for?

Comment: thats pretty much the expected behavior...you might want to specify what you expect to happen...is there a web server behind the firewall you expect to be exposed?

Comment: Same as:  http://serverfault.com/questions/285758/cisco-router-website-doesnt-work-locally-because-public-ip-directs-to-router-i

Answer (score 0):

The IP address that you have bought or leased from the ISP is currently being assigned to your router's WAN interface as its own IP address so that all traffic from your LAN can be Port Address Translated through that single IP address. So that public IP no longer refers to just your machine itself, but to your entire network since you are effectively sharing the services provided through that single IP address to your entire network. When you specify the port with ":80" you are actually pointing towards the web (Port 80) interface of your own router which is accessed through its interfaces, WAN in this case.

What you need to do is configure a DNS server in your network which will route any lookup for a query to your site's url to the local IP address of the webserver on your LAN on which the site resides. For eg: if your DNS Server is on 192.168.1.15 and the Webserver on which your site is, is on 192.168.1.30, then create a DNS entry routing traffic  destined to your website URL to 192.168.1.30 where the IES will direct it to the site on its drive.

Hope that answers your query.